# Keyboard closed when I clicked on select2 input

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

When I click on select2 input keyboard closed

```
 $('select').on('select2:open', function(e) {
    $('.select2-search input').prop('focus',false);
 });
```

please check this [video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G9Q75EQKUrY0yIpXxPR49sieEuYTGPVa)

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly for your function. Your function say if input2 got selected focouse out so its something like you hasn't clicked it ever!
Explain more bout what do you want to achieve and I can help you more.

Comment: Do you have same problem on other inputs or just this one?

Comment: Oh, I see. Other inputs have this problem too.

Comment: Kavya please share your HTML and JS file so I can see what is going wrong. It might be a problem with other functions on your js.